# Marketing Cloud - Create a Data Extension by filtering out Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, audience

big Marketing Cloud Noob here!

I have inherited the admin Role in the Company in Marketing Cloud and I cannot make ends meet.

My Company regularly sends emails to their subscribers and professionals we have registered on our website.

Our list of subscribers is stored in data extension file. than we have several where subscribers are filtered by country (As you might see from the image)

here is a portion of the screen:
[image: example image]

I want to be able, to create another list where Mexicans audience is filtered out.

I just cant find a way! Im not asking you to guide me step by step, but maybe sending me some useful material I can study. Checked out trailhead and found nothing related.

[image]

So, this is a print screen of our Subscribers and the field related.
I should be able to filter a different audience by Country code but doesn't work!

Comment: The data extension for countries you see are filtered DEs. You can read here to know how to create it https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_filtered_de.htm&type=5

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me. I filtered the data extension with all the subscribers and from +200000 records I obtained 0! I know it is not true! how can it be?

Comment: Can you put more information about the data extension source you used to filter out? Like which field and value you were using in the filter? Then I can take a look at it

Comment: @DucLe I updated the post so you can see a print screen of my data ext. and its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your source DE screenshot, I would guide you like this:

1. From the source DE, click on the funnel icon on the top right corner
2. Drag the field "CountryCode" from the left column to the Create Filter canvas
3. Put a value for the filter. For example: CountryCode is equal to "MX" (I am assuming that the MX value is using for Mexican audiences)
4. Click "Save & Build"
5. Enter a Name for the filtered data extension and Select a folder to store the filtered DE
6. Save and wait until it completely finishes.

Actually, it will perform the same steps as the document I mentioned in my comment, but from the DE source

Answer (score 0):

To find the distinct values of the CountryCode field and the number of related contacts, you can use the following query in Query Studio:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), CountryCode
FROM [DE Name]
GROUP BY CountryCode
```

This will give you a list of all the different country codes that exist in the data extension along with the number of contacts associated with each one.

Then you can take the exact CountryCode value for Mexico for use in your Filtered Data Extension.

Comment: This list was imported from the List of accounts present in our Salesforce. Unless fields might change moving from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud I doubt it will work but I will try what you suggested anyway and see how it goes. Thank you.